# Changing port for sshd.socket

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sshd, systemctl

I recently installed Arch Linux ARM on my Raspberry Pi. I wanted to build a small webserver with an SSH access. (It's currently only accessible via LAN but I want to change that in the future.) The system is up to date (i.e. updated 2 hours ago)

To at least somewhat increase the security of the SSH connection, I wanted to change the port to some other number, e.g. 65022.

Therefore, I changed my sshd_config and the corresponding unit file for systemd.

UnitFile:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=sshd.service
Wants=sshdgenkeys.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=65022
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

sshd_conf:

```
Port 65022
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

The output of `systemctl status sshd.socket`:

```
sshd.socket
Loaded:loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.socket; enabeld; vendor preset:disabled)
Active: active(listening) since DATE
Listen: [:::]:65022 (Stream)
Accepted: 0; Connected: 0
```

`netstat | grep 65022` shows no listening program.

It worked with 65022 until I restarted the system, it reverted back to 22 and after I changed the unit file it seems to be refusing all connections. If I change the unit file back to `ListenStream=22` it works on port 22. What did I miss?